# Tesseract on Windows: Outputs are always innacurate

Tags: tesseract-ocr

So I'm trying to OCR this image: (This are actually usernames)

[image]

using this command on the Windows command prompt:

```
tesseract screenshot.png out
```

However the out.txt always brings innacurate results. In this case it is:

```
belsahx
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the white text on a black background bringing problems. Im using the English language pack by the way.

To confirm the problem, this image:

[image]

produces this:

```
1akvDZ\ 5
```

Comment: spell checker? :) There is nothing resembling an `x` in the pic. Must be some post precessing.

Comment: Does tesseract use a spell checker? I dont understand